# downloading modules from Command prompt

Tags: python

I've tried to obtain multiple modules via the command prompt and it says it's download everything, yet when I then try to import the module via code it doesn't work.

I've tried the google and discord modules and they downloaded but then were not being recognized when referenced

## *Discordbot Code*

```
import discord
client = discord.Client()
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("The bot is ready!")
    await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name="Making a    bot"))
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content == "Hello":
        await client.send_message(message.channel, "World")
client.run(the bot link)
```

I downloaded matplotlib and when I referenced it in code it worked.

Comment: How are you downloading them? Most likely you have a virtual environment or multiple versions of python that is causing a problem.

Comment: So in my python folder, I have a folder called Python36-32 which is the version I want to use, and then I have Python37 which is the version I uninstalled. So should I delete the latter folder?

Comment: Before you do that could you include the commands you are entering plus the error message you are getting?